# Padding appears when I generate the same code from javascript

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple stacked row class which shows the upper box and lower box without padding.

```
<span id="route" class="small">
<div class="row" style="border-style:solid;">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-12">
    <p>UpperBox</p>
    <p>UpperBox</p>
    <p>UpperBox</p>
    <p>UpperBox</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row" style="border-style:solid;">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-12">
        <p>LowereBox</p>
        <p>LowereBox</p>
        <p>LowereBox</p>
    </div>
</div>
</span>
```

However when I put the same source code dynamically by javascript.

There appears the padding between two vertical boxes.

DO you think what is the cause of problem?

```
div.push(`
  <div class="row" style="border-style:solid;">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-12">
    <p>UpperBox</p>
    <p>UpperBox</p>
    <p>UpperBox</p>
    <p>UpperBox</p>
    </div>
  </div>
`);

div.push(`
  <div class="row" style="border-style:solid;">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-12">
        <p>LowereBox</p>
        <p>LowereBox</p>
        <p>LowereBox</p>
    </div>
  </div>
`);

$('#route').html(div.join());
```

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: maybe use `.join('')`? as not specifying seperator would join with a comma

Comment: Your second one has a lots more spaces between the two divs than your first one (even ignoring @shrys' good point about `join`). In HTML a single whitespace vs. a run of whitespace shouldn't matter, but...

Comment: There's a fundamental problem, though: That's invalid HTML. You can't put a [`div`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) inside a [`span`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element). The content model of `span` is phrasing content, but `div`s are valid in flow content (and `dl`s). When you present the browser with invalid HTML, it's free to do basically anything it wants, including reordering things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just to specify the join delimiter, it's `,` comma by default, change it to blank instead `.join('')` like :

```
$('#route').html(div.join(''));
```

```js
let div = [];

div.push(`<div class="row" style="border-style:solid;">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-12">
    <p>UpperBox</p>
    <p>UpperBox</p>
    <p>UpperBox</p>
    <p>UpperBox</p>
    </div>
</div>`);

div.push(`<div class="row" style="border-style:solid;">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-12">
        <p>LowereBox</p>
        <p>LowereBox</p>
        <p>LowereBox</p>
    </div>
</div>`);

$('#route').html(div.join(''));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="route" class="small"></span>
```

Comment: You should mention you've removed *other* whitespace as well.

Comment: Thank you verymuch!! it hits my spit!!! I have struggled only tag for a long time...However there is a problem on Javascript